# I wonder is there any other way?? Javascript

Tags: javascript, function

I'm looking for another way to replace this sentence.
(counter.set = (value) => count = value; counter.decrease = () =. count --)
how can i do that??

```
   function makeCounter() {
      let count = 0;
    
      function counter() {
        return count++
      }

      // Issue --
      counter.set = (value) => count = value;
      counter.decrease = () => count--;
      // End of issue --

      return counter;
    }
    
    let counter = makeCounter();
    
    alert( counter() ); // 0
    alert( counter() ); // 1
    
    counter.set(10); // set the new count
    
    alert( counter() ); // 10
    
    counter.decrease(); // decrease the count by 1
    
    alert( counter() ); // 10 (instead of 11)
```

Comment: Clearly stated, what's the problem?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. If the code is functional then this is primarily opinion based therefore off topic. There is a StackExchange site for this type of question called Code Review. Voting to close this.

Comment: Normally this would be done using a class or object with a prototype, not adding properties to a function.

Answer (score 1):

you need to use new keyword to change it ... also you can use class

```
 class makeCounter  {
    constructor(){
       this.count = 0;
    }
      
      function counter() {
        return count++
      }

      set(value){ this.count = value;}
     decrease(){this.count-- ;}

      
    }
    
    let counter =new makeCounter();
    
    alert( counter() ); // 0
    alert( counter() ); // 1
    
    counter.set(10); // set the new count
    
    alert( counter() ); // 10
    
    counter.decrease(); // decrease the count by 1
    
    alert( counter() ); // 10 (instead of 11)
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use a class

```js
class Counter {
  constructor() {
    this.count = 0;
  }
  
  set(value) {
    this.count = value;
  }
  
  increase(value) {
    this.count += (value || 1);
  }
  
  decrease(value) {
    this.count -= (value || 1);
  }
}

const counter = new Counter();

console.log(counter.count);

counter.increase();

console.log(counter.count);

counter.increase();

console.log(counter.count);

counter.increase(10);

console.log(counter.count);

counter.decrease();

console.log(counter.count);

counter.decrease(2);

console.log(counter.count);
```